# How can I inhibit git@example.com in preference to git@tweak.example.com?

Tags: git, ssh

I have multiple accounts on a Git-based forge[1], and I want to check out and manage repos via SSH (not HTTPS). I currently do this by:

- creating different key files for each account
- in my SSH config, creating a fake host per account
- assigning each key file as an IdentityFile to the matching fake host
- performing Git tasks with git@fake.example.com rather than git@example.com

(This follows the advice given [here on SO](https://superuser.com/a/366656/29994) and [elsewhere](https://vparihar01.github.io/setup/2013/04/03/multiple-ssh-keys-settings-for-different-github-account/).)

```
Host id1.example.com
  Hostname example.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host id2.example.com
  Hostname example.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I can now `ssh -T git@id1.example.com` or `ssh -T git@id2.example.com` and perform Git tasks similarly.

However, I can *also* still perform Git tasks with `git@example.com`, which seems to be associated with my default id_rsa key. I attempted to override this as follows:

```
Host example.com
  Hostname example.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/none
```

...where `~/.ssh/none` is a text file containing dummy text. However, an ssh attempt still succeeds, associated with my default id_rsa key.

How can I override this case so that attempts fail, forcing me to explicitly use one of the account-specific hosts?

[1] So far I know that this applies to GitHub and BitBucket, but I imagine there is a general principle at work here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to remove the `id_rsa.key` file to prevent SSH from finding a "default" authentication key.

***CAUTION!*** Have a backup of that file! And of course, keep the configured `IdentityFile` keys. Just don't have an `id_rsa.key` in your `~/.ssh`.